# MediaWiki expression: #ifeq: {{ns:0}}

Tags: mediawiki

I have encountered a MediaWiki exression:

```
{{#ifeq: {{ns:0}} | {{{1}}} | Example is absent. | {{{1}}}}
}}
```

Is it a MediaWiki-way to test *{{{1}}}* for being blank?

Answer (score 3):

I never saw this expression in this combination, however, from what I could reconstruct from the documentation, you're absolutely right.

First, let's break the expression down:

- First we have the syntax `{{#ifeq: string1 | string2 | present | absent }}`. It is an expression from the ParserFunctions extension (see [documentation here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions##ifeq)) and basically compares the two strings `string1` and `string2` and "returns" the appropriate strings (`absent` or `present`).
- The second one is `{{ns:}}` which [returns the localized name for the namespace](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Namespaces_2) in which the current page is (or the localized name of the specified namespace). The namespace `0` [is always the main namespace](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Namespace) and has basically no localized name (an empty string as a localized name).

So, basically the expression is checking, it the string2 is equal to the result of `{{ns:0}}`, which is an empty string.

However, to be honest, I don't know why one would do that complicated `#ifeq` check. The ParserFunctions extension also provides the [`#if` function](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions##if) which does exactly that. It evaluates the passed string if it is empty or not. So, your example could probably be simpler expressed with:

```
{{#if: {{{1}}} | {{{1}}}} | Example is absent. }}
```